# MS access link to external data source SQL failed

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

My Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus updated to  Version 1708 (Build 8431.2153) since then all of my MS Access external links to SQL are given the  error code “ODBC-failed”
Only small tables pop up. I have changed the connection pooling for SOL into “ not pooled” via de ODBC Data Source Administrator but this doesn’t help. How can I solve this?
Thank you